# Highcharts chart option backgroundColor:'transparent' showing black on IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, highcharts

`Highcharts` chart option `backgroundColor:'transparent'` showing black on `IE 8`

```
histogram = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: { renderTo: 'histogram', defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
                     backgroundColor:'transparent'
            }
```

This works fine on `I.E 9` and others but fails on I.E 8 and Safari anyone has any idea why ?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
histogram = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: { renderTo: 'histogram', defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
                         backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)'
                }
```

Comment: Is not entirely transparent.  The box is clearly seen. nessa.gp's answer worked for me.

Comment: That's a workaround. Works better with `backgroundColor:null`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. @ViniciusPires your solutions doesn't work for me (I see black background).

Comment: plotBackgroundImage: null, also might help

Comment: backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)' will give you complete transparency

Comment: Null no longer works in HighCharts 6. Use backgroundColor: 'transparent' instead. (Tested on all modern browsers and IE11+).

Answer (score 133):

Can you try this -

```
backgroundColor: null
```

**See on: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGurung/LZ8Mu/)**

Comment: Mayuresh's answer it's a good alternative but this works too and looks more clean.

Comment: Perfect! If I only had 10 upvotes to give :) This is certainly the correct, elegant, not-a-hack solution.

Comment: I agree; this should probably be the top answer.

Comment: Your fiddle is broken now that Highcharts has moved the .js file you linked to. As mentioned elsewhere null will not always work. nessa.gp's answer gives the best case values for each browser, as discovered by Highcharts themselves.

Comment: it also fixes whkhtmltopdf problem with black background.

Comment: Null no longer works in HighCharts 6. Use backgroundColor: 'transparent' instead. (Tested on all modern browsers and IE11+).

Comment: @Stevethemacguy Do you have a sample (jsfiddle) to illustrate? Or is there a documentation?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BGurung/5w7xymnb/ Seems to be working but you are also right that `'transparent'` is also working.

Answer (score 9):

I found this in Highcharts sources:

> Empirical lowest possible opacities for TRACKER_FILL
>
> - IE6: 0.002
> - IE7: 0.002
> - IE8: 0.002
> - IE9: 0.00000000001 (unlimited)
> - IE10: 0.0001 (exporting only)
> - FF: 0.00000000001 (unlimited)
> - Chrome: 0.000001
> - Safari: 0.000001
> - Opera: 0.00000000001 (unlimited)
>
> TRACKER_FILL = 'rgba(192,192,192,' + (hasSVG ? 0.0001 : 0.002) + ')'

So you can set the chart background color to 'rgba(255,255,255,0.002)' and it runs in the most important browsers.

Answer (score 2):

`backgroundColor: 'transparent'` also working if you need type safety.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this :

```
.highcharts-background {
   fill: transparent;
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css?_ga=2.181016679.1735310361.1641809052-1721279916.1639430160)

Full example:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        styledMode: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart border and background by CSS'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        floating: true,
        align: 'left',
        x: 100,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 70
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

```css
@import "https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css";

.highcharts-background {
    fill: #efefef;
    stroke: #a4edba;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: You rock. Thanks for this. None of the other solutions were working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the highcharts.js file go to the backgroundColor line (around  479) and change line like `backgroundColor:"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)"`. It will change all backgrounds of the charts to transparent

Comment: And then you will have to do that every time you update the library.

Answer (score -2):

May be you have to write

```
filter:0 !important;
```

in your css.

Answer (score -2):

```
backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.