# Debugging jQuery flot color/canvas plot error on IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, canvas, flot

Im in trouble with the use of **jQuery Flot with a Twitter Bootstrap template**, because all runs perfectly on Chrome, but on IE 10 and Firefox it doesn´t. :(

I´ve tried too many inspects, looking some solution on Google, without any light... so Im claiming here for some help!

You´re gonna understand what Im talking about if you run these 2 cases on Chrome, FF and IE:

> **First Case - PIE Graph:**
>
> http://www.frontsite.com.br/ccee/relatorio2013/30-comercializacao-30.html
>
> Perfect on Chrome, but on IE and FF it becomes a totaly black circle.
>   (?!)

---

> **Second Case - SERIES Type**
>
> http://www.frontsite.com.br/ccee/relatorio2013/30-comercializacao-20.html
>
> Perfect on Chrome, but on IE and FF the lines becomes GREY. (?!)

---

> **Third Case - BARs Type - Runs fine! :)**
>
> http://www.frontsite.com.br/ccee/relatorio2013/30-comercializacao-85.html
>
> Its the only correct case that runs perfect on both three browsers. :)

I really spent too much time inspecting this problem, and now Im using this channel to take some professional help... could someone help me? Any lights???

Thanks.
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colors are not specified correctly, you have a trailing semi-colon (`"#1572bf;"` should be `"#1572bf"`):

```
var dados1 = [
    { label: "<b>Comercialização</b> 75,4%",  data: 75.4, color: "#1572bf;<-- THIS IS INVALID" },
    { label: "<b>Distribuição</b> 2,0%",  data: 2, color: "#bfd730;<-- THIS IS INVALID" },
    { label: "<b>Geração</b> 22,6%",  data: 22.6, color: "#f99d33;<-- THIS IS INVALID" }
];
```

Here's a [before and after fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8k57/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You might check these other links - I found them helpful when I experienced the same issue.

```
grid : {
    background    : 'transparent',
    gridLineColor : '#c5c5c5'
}
```

- [Highcharts chart option backgroundColor:'transparent' showing black on IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736385/highcharts-chart-option-backgroundcolortransparent-showing-black-on-ie-8)
- [jqplot graph background seems to be black in ie8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571743/jqplot-graph-background-seems-to-be-black-in-ie8)