# Remove background from Highchart heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want remove the background from the highchart heatmap, as you can see in the image below i remove the highchart background but not the background inside the plot:
[image]

Anyone knows how can I achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: I think your questions is almost a duplicate that is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736385/highcharts-chart-option-backgroundcolortransparent-showing-black-on-ie-8).

Comment: You want to remove the labels.?

Comment: the `bacgroundColor` option seem to works fine, look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/w38pdkx7/)

Comment: no, it's not a duplicate, as you can see in the x and y label there is no background, I alreday remove it, in the plot insted beside the little square you se the white, i want remove that color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the white space are sqares with value 0 you need to set the `minColor` to a transparent value

```
colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/w38pdkx7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Img]

To remove white border surrounding square you have to update series with

```
  "series":[
  {
     "borderWidth":0,
      .........
  }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xj8jznq9/) demo